# php email form help-how to help

Tags: php, forms

how i can make a php email form , that can send 1 email to 20 emails or from where i can make this types of free email form php script.

Comment: Take a look at the `mail()` function. There are some good examples for that ;-). http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

To make an email form you will simply collect the data and process it. I will write a quick example below (this is not throttling enabled; google "e-mail throttling" for more information).

some_page.php

```
<form name="email-form" method="post" action="process_email.php">
<?php
for(int i=0;i<20;++i)
{
    print "Friend E-mail".$i."<br />".
    "<input type=\"text\" name=\"email[".$i."]\" /><br />";
}
?>
Message to send to users:
<textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="10">Type your message here...</textarea><br /><br />
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Send e-mails\" /> <input type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset Form\" />
</form>
```

In the file above, you create a form with method="post" and action="LOCATION_OF_PROCESS_SCRIPT.php". This way it sends the form data collected to the script which should process the e-mail.

Now to process the form:

process_email.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['message'] == NULL)
{
    print "Please enter a message to send to your users.";
    exit;
}
foreach($_POST['email'] as $key => $val)
{
    if($val == NULL) continue; // Skip null e-mails
    mail($val,"Some subject",$_POST['message']);
}
?>
```

This is where all the information is processed. This simply sends out an e-mail with a static subject line to the e-mail specified with the message content specified in the form for the corresponding user.

Now, this is a very simple example but does everything you're asking for. You collect form data in array form, then you process your form arrays and send the messages accordingly. If you have further questions, feel free to ask. This list 20 e-mail forms, but skips blanks (in either e-mail or message). You can customize the form more, etc, but like I said: basic. Note that I did not debug this, but I'm pretty sure you shouldn't get any parsing errors.

Updated to send **one** email up to **twenty** users!

Good luck!
Dennis M.

Comment: You check if `$val == NULL` but `continue`? Apart from that - it is possible to send ONE mail to MORE recipients ;-)...

Comment: @thedom: ah, I will update the code xD I misread it. But as far as $val == NULL continue goes, continue will restart the loop but not process anything after. So if the e-mail $val == NULL, then it won't attempt to send an e-mail.

Comment: of course - you are right with `continue`... I think I need some `sleep(calcSecondsTill('07:00'))` :).